# Control-E in Tmux does not bring me to end-of-line

Tags: tmux

I am having an issue with Tmux where <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> brings me to the end of a line outside of Tmux but not inside of Tmux. I have looked around for a solution but none seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. My .tmux.conf can be seen here: https://gist.github.com/Julian25/6585115

Comment: What is the OS tmux running on?

In my iTerm of Mac, the `Ctrl+E` works normally to the end of file, but the `Ctrl+A` to the beginning of line should change to `Ctrl+A` then `A`, because I changed <a> as tmux prefix.

Answer (score 11):

if you are using zsh, try adding `bindkey -e` to your .zshrc file.

Comment: Thank you so much!